# SurfaceView lost initial drawing. Double buffer initialization?

Tags: android, performance, animation, graphics, surfaceview

I'm using `SurfaceView` for driving sprites.

For performance, I only redraw `canvas` partially, so I lock the Canvas with dirty rect. In general, it works good, but `SurfaceView` lost initial drawing in `surfaceCreated` method.

I suppose it's related to `SurfaceView` internal double buffering.

Any ideas how to correctly initialize `SurfaceView`?

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class TestView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private static final String TAG = TestView.class.getSimpleName();
    SurfaceHolder holder;

    public TestView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        holder = getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(this);
        setFocusable(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        drawBg();
        drawPoint(100, 120);
    }

    private void drawBg() {
        Canvas canvas = null;
        try {
            canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
            synchronized (holder) {
                canvas.drawRGB(255, 128, 128);
                Paint paint = new Paint();
                paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                canvas.drawCircle(100, 100, 10, paint);
            }
        } finally {
            if (canvas != null) {
                holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }
    }

    private void drawPoint(int x, int y) {
        int radius = 10;
        Rect dirty = new Rect(x - radius, y - radius, x + radius, y + radius);
        Canvas canvas = null;
        try {
            canvas = holder.lockCanvas(dirty);
            synchronized (holder) {
                Paint paint = new Paint();
                paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radius, paint);
            }
        } finally {
            if (canvas != null) {
                holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i2, int i3) {}

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {}


    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            drawPoint((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Comment: SurfaceViews are used for continuous drawing using a thread.

Comment: Yes, this code just simplified.

Comment: The "dirty" rect is an in-out parameter.  If Surface is unable to restore the previous "front" buffer it will expand the dirty rect to cover the entire screen.

Comment: Thank you very much, fadden. So in real application animation thread should report to main thread in case "dirty" rect changed. Main thread should stop animation, redraw surface and start animation.